# Can Neural Networks using ReLU activation work without using the bias term in their neurons?

Tags: neural-networks, relu

I created a super simple NN of 1 input, 2 hidden layers of 2 neurons each and 1 output neuron as shown below.

[image: Fully connected layer structure]

All activations are ReLUs and neurons doesn't use the bias term. What I found is that the output graph is a combination of two linear functions (one when the input is negative and another when the input is positive) kind of like this.

[image: Output graph]

I think without the bias term, the output will be a linear function (for negative and positive inputs separately) no matter how big the network is. My question is, is this useful at all as an architecture? I assume it might be - if multiple output nodes are available, or is it? Does any of this mean that the a bias term is mandatory? Just trying to get my intuition right here...